# Javascript goes past for loop and then back to it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to make a simple stopwatch that counts by milliseconds in javascript using setTimeout, and I ran into this problem in the initial stages:

```js
var time = 0;

function main() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    setTimeout(timer, 1);
  }
  alert(time + " after the for loop");
}

function timer() {
  time++;
  alert(time + " in the for loop");
}

document.getElementById("go").onclick = main;
```

```css
#go {
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid lime;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<button id="go">Start!</button>
```

This piece of code seems to skip past the for loop to the alert, then go back to the for loop. What is happening here? I have some basic experience programming in python, and in python if you call a function within a function the function you called will be executed before the next line of code in the main function is processed. Is this how javascript works? Please forgive me if my code looks terrible I am new to html/css/javascript.

Comment: It seems like the for loop executes much faster than the 1 ms setTimeout delay, and finishes before the timer callback functions gets called. However, setTimeout is a task which blocks the main thread, so it should continue past it either way. It’s quite interesting this, but I can’t give you an exact answer.

Comment: You should really be using `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout` in a for loop

Comment: setTimeout does not block the main thread. It's not like python sleep().

Comment: `setTimeout` is far from being precise. It may be delayed because of other parts of your script may take precedence.

Comment: @ivo Oh, my bad. Messed up my own logic there. I guess I can blame lack of knowledge, uncertainty and that it’s 3:30 am here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `setTimeout(timer, 1)` the `timer` function will be called asynchronously after the amount of time you specified (in your case 1ms).

The code continues to run (it doesn't wait for the timeout to complete - that's the point of it being asynchronous - it's non-blocking) - thus the `" after the loop"` alert shows before the other ones do.

Comment: The function specified in setTimeout() will only be called after the current function returns to the Javascript internal event loop. No matter how much time has elapsed, the alert() after the loop will be called first.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the setTimeout function is asynchronous.

Think of it as the setTimeout function go away to another place(call web api) to wait for one second(so the `alert(time + " after the for loop");` will run first) then it passes to the event loop and finally run the timer function.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout()` is asynchronous, it starts a timer in the background and calls your function at some point later.  You may be thinking of it like a sleep statement, which it is not.

For real usage, it is often nice to use a closure function:

```
setTimeout(function() { alert('My alert'); }, 1000);
```

Also note that the timeout is in milliseconds, so `1` is practically instant!